# Logic to prepare SQL statements dynamically

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle

So i have a requirement where I need to read through records of all records of a file and insert them into another file if they meet a set of rules which are described in another table as shown below..

[image]

A record after it has been read from the first file has to meet all the sequences of at least one Rule to make it eligible to be written into the Second table.

For example once a record is read from CAR file, the rules below have to be checked till all sequences of atleast one rule set is satisfied. For this I was planning to Create a dynamic SQL program something of this sort. But this does not work as Prepared SQL does not support host variables.

[image]

If any body can suggest or provide any guidance on how to create SQL statemtns dynamically and check if records satisfy the required rules for them to be entered into the second file, it would be great

So basically what I am looking for is once I select a field from a table, how do I store it somehere to do further validation and checking.

> Update

:

Based on the intelligent advice from Danny117, I have come up with the below code:

```
H Option(*NoDebugIO:*SrcStmt)                                    
D RULEDS        E DS                  EXTNAME(RULESTABLE)        
D MAXRUL          S              1  0                            
D MAXSEQ          S              1  0                            
D STMT            S            512                               
D WHERESTMT       S            512    INZ('')                    
D FullSqlStmt     S            512    INZ('')                    
D RULINDEX        S              1  0 INZ(1)                     
D SEQINDEX        S              1  0 INZ(1)                     
D APOS            C                   CONST('''')                
  /Free                                                          
    Exec SQL SELECT MAX(RULENO)INTO :MAXRUL FROM RULESTABLE;     
    Exec SQL DECLARE RULCRS CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM RULESTABLE; 
    Exec SQL OPEN RULCRS;                                        
    Exec SQL FETCH RULCRS INTO :RULEDS;                          
    DoW (Sqlcod = 0 AND RULINDEX <= MAXRUL);                     
      Exec SQL SELECT MAX(SEQNO) INTO :MAXSEQ FROM RULESTABLE    
      WHERE RULENO=:RULINDEX ;                                   
      DoW (SEQINDEX <= MAXSEQ);                                  
   If (Position <> '');                                     
     Field = 'SUBSTR('+%Trim(Field)+','+%Trim(Position)+',' 
     +'1'+')';                                              
   EndIf;                                                   
   WhereStmt = %Trim(WhereStmt) + ' ' + %Trim(field)+ ' ' + 
   %Trim(condition) + ' ' + APOS + %Trim(Value) + APOS;     

   If (SeqIndex < MaxSeq);                                  
     WhereStmt = %Trim(WhereStmt) + ' AND ';                
   EndIf;                                                   


   Exec SQL FETCH NEXT FROM RULCRS INTO :RULEDS;            
   SeqIndex = SeqIndex + 1;                                 
 EndDo;                                                     
 FullSqlStmt = %Trim('INSERT INTO ITMRVAT SELECT * +        
 FROM ITMRVA WHERE '+ %Trim(WhereStmt));                    
 Exec SQL Prepare InsertStmt from :FullSqlStmt;             
 Exec SQL EXECUTE InsertStmt;                               
  RulIndex = RulIndex + 1;
EndDo;
```

This produces SQL statement as shown below which is what I want. Now let me go ahead and look at the other parts of the code.

```
 > EVAL FullSqlStmt                                                       
  FULLSQLSTMT =                                                          
            ....5...10...15...20...25...30...35...40...45...50...55...60 
       1   'INSERT INTO ITMRVAT SELECT * FROM ITMRVA WHERE STID = 'PLD' '
      61   'AND ENGNO LIKE '%415015%' AND SUBSTR(ENGNO,1,1) = 'R' AND SU'
     121   'BSTR(ENGNO,5,1) = 'Y'                                       '
     181   '                                                            '
     241   '                                                            '
     301   '                                                            '
     361   '                                                            '
     421   '                                                            '
     481   '                                '
```

But the issue is now as I mentioned in my comment to Danny, how to handle if a new rule involving second table is specified..

Comment: Dynamically with what means: using a programming language like [tag:c], using scripting....

Comment: I am trying to write an Embedded SQLRPG program . RPG is the main language used in the IBM i platform. But i think this does not matter as the doubt is on DB2

Comment: Impossible for us to say how to handle a second table referenced in rules. Show us an example that includes results when a second table is referenced, then it might become clear.

Comment: So i won the battle with the Analyst here ! He had to agree the current setup of the rulestable is simply not good enough to handle multiple tables. A phase 2 of the project has been forked now to handle this

Comment: Warning - blanket trim-and-concatenate leaves you wide open to SQL Injection.  A full rule-writing procedure is complex, but at the minimum you need to verify that the values in the columns are whitelisted elements.  Table/field columns should be checked to verify the only thing entered is a column/field name.  You most likely want to add a 'type' column of sort sort to say what the `value` column is, and possibly an additional "table" column (for if the value is a reference to another table).  You want to do this with parameter markers for all values otherwise, though.

Comment: Saving rules requires a rule creation app.  I just save the where clause or the join clause.  Outdated designed systems that save the equals sign oh crap I need to have two or's or three ands.  It just gets out of hand saving every element of the clause in a seperate column of a rule table.  The 1970s called they want there design back.  So @Clockwork-Muse please run away screaming from my KISS design and KISS my rule creation app sign off on it so it doesn't allow injection.  Thanks I will put or (1=1) in a column of a 1970's style rule table and we'll see how each design can be beaten.

Comment: @danny117 - the problem is that, while the query-generation phase may be simple, the loading app (and the server side verification, if that happens client side) needs to perform the exact same validation - the app will not be simple.  This gets worse if at least some users have update access to those tables: they could potentially write rules that change some other part of the system they don't normally have access to (that is, not a full-trust admin).  Good security is _hard_, and I'd rather make my life a little more difficult to set up a system more difficult to subvert.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  1st rule of security don't invent your own security.

Comment: ....exactly.  By explicitly delineating things like this, I essentially need "no" security, because things are constrained from the beginning.  There's no way to supply arbitrary code in place of a value, no way to have untrusted statements be run.  With the design you're proposing, you have to do a **lot** of hard work, every time the rule is run, to make sure that the contained code is safe; depending on where the statements are being added, it may be possible to do things like but data-change-tables into the rule, which would be a security problem.  Or other, worse things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to translate the rules into a join statement or a where clause.  The join statement is more complex so go that route.

If you were smart (and you are) consider saving the rules as a SQL clause that you can join or use in a where clause.  Its infinitely flexible this way a more modern design.

rule 1 /  car.year = 1990 and car.engno like '%43243%' and substring(car.vin,12,1) = 'X'

```
eval statement = 
insert into sometable
Select car.* from car  
join sysibm.sysdummy1 
on car.year = 1990 
and car.engno lile '%43243%'
```

...etc on to rule 2 starting with "OR"

```
or car.year = PLD
and car.engno like '%1234%'
```

...etc other rules starting with "OR"

```
exec immediate statement
```

Comment: This seems to be the right approach here.. I will go ahead with this and see

Comment: This seems to be the ideal approach if the RULE table is gonna include only one table. i.e CAR. But suppose if the user enters in a rule based on another table say like FILE = CAR_LOCATION, FIELD = CITY , CONDITION = '=', and VALUE = 'IOMA'  as one of the sequence of a rule set. That is the business want to insert only those car details which are in a particular location.  This would definitely require knowledge of the field that links the CAR table and the LOCATION table. Am I right? PLease share your thoughts

Comment: No it could be every table in your enterprise you have to get to that level of thinking.  NoSQL but somewhere there is SQL.  It's like quantum physics way past how friction works against acceleration and keeping an object in motion.

Comment: Sorry english please? :P  Suppose there are two tables that need to be checked. But all the user keys into the rule table is the name of the tables, the fields , the conditions and the values they should have. How can the program know what field to use to join the two tables? There is no way I suppose with the info that is in the rule table?

Comment: I would run screaming from this: you're allowing arbitrary clauses to be specified, probably from untrusted users.  You're advocating a design that expressly allows SQL Injection!  Whereas the original design would prevent that by being checkable.

Comment: See comment above about injection and poor designs.

Answer (score 3):

Embedded SQL does allow for 'dynamic statements' in ILE languages. You are able to have a query within a character field and then pass it into the Embedded SQL.

```
Dcl-S lQuery Varchar(100);

lQuery = 'SELECT * FROM CUST';

EXEC SQL
  PREPARE SCust FROM :lQuery;
EXEC SQL
  DECLARE SearchCust CURSOR FOR SCust;

//Continue working with cursor..
```

You may want to just prepare, execute and return a result set:

```
lQuery = 'SELECT * FROM CUST WHERE ID = ' + %Char(CustID);

EXEC SQL
  PREPARE SCust FROM :lQuery;

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SCust;
OPEN c1;
FETCH c1 INTO :CustDS;
CLOSE c1;
```

Optional extra: You may also want to use field markers (?) in your query.

```
//'SELECT * FROM CUST WHERE CUSTID = ?';
EXEC SQL OPEN SearchCust USING :CustID;

//'INSERT INTO CUST VALUES(?,?)';
EXEC SQL EXECUTE CUST USING :CustID;
```

Comment: I know all these. But what I am trying to do now is write something like this: STMT = 'SELECT ' + %TRIM(FIELD) + ' INTO :STID FROM ' +%TRIM(FILE) +  ' WHERE RRN(ITMRVA) = 1'; EXEC SQL PREPARE SQLSTMT FROM :STMT; which is failing with SQLCOD -312 probably because SELECT INTO is used. How do i prepare a statement like this?

Comment: @user3311539 Remove the INTOs from the query, PREPARE the query using the example above, then EXECUTE the prepared statement with the INTO clause. I will update my answer to show you.

Comment: I presume CUSTDS is an external data structure defined with as EXTNAME(CUST). So if am selecting, just one variable, this should work:EXEC SQL EXECUTE SQLSTMT INTO :STID; but this doesnt work and the error is Token : was not valid. Valid tokens: SQL DESCRIPTOR.

Comment: @user3311539 my fault... I updated my answer to have a working dynamic select statement. I misread the docs, INTO is not supported with EXECUTE.

Comment: This is getting messy now. Since the field to which a cursor value needs to be fetched can be determined only at run time, I have written something like Stmt = 'Fetch EXSQCRS INTO ?';          
EXEC SQL PREPARE SQLSTMT2 FROM :STMT ; But this is hailing with -302 SQLCOD. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry the sqlcod is -104

Comment: "May" want to use field markers?  **Yes, yes you do**.  To do otherwise is to invite SQL Injection.